# Starting out with Objective C; need some guidance

Tags: iphone

I have started learning Objective C with no prior programming experience from the 'Become an X-Coder' eBook (http://download.cocoalab.com.s3.amazonaws.com/BecomeAnXcoder.pdf). My question is, if I want to be doing iPhone development, am I going in the right direction? Am I learning the wrong language, or should I be learning Cocoa Touch? As I said, I have no prior experience, and just need someone to point me in the right direction. Apoligies if I have put this in the wrong place. Thanks very much for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is that Cocoa Touch *is* Objective-C. And now for the long answer...

Objective-C is the essence of Cocoa Touch, which refers to the [frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_framework) which are built by Apple for iOS development. So basically, if you are learning Objective-C, you *are* learning part of [Cocoa Touch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoa_Touch). Cocoa touch refers specifically to the code libraries and frameworks written for the iPhone and iPad.

If you are starting out, you may want to learn C and then Objective-C. However, it's totally up to you. It may be helpful to know C, but not required.

If you decide to go with Objective-C as a first language, I recommend getting some books on the Objective-C language as well as some books on iOS development. I have read Head First iPhone Development (O'Reilly)[Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596803540) | [Google](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?hl=en&safe=active&q=head+first+iPhone&um=1&ie=UTF-8&cid=11319371281040728925&ei=bg4hTd2yKsH58AbUh_G6Dg&sa=X&oi=product_catalog_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CC8Q8wIwAg) and [Sams Teach Yourself iPhone Development in 24 hours (Amazon)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672330849). Someone recommended looking into a publisher called Apress, but I haven't yet. There are also some great blogs to look at once you you get started. Matt Gallagher's [Cocoa with Love](http://cocoawithlove.com/) is not a beginners blog, but it has some nice information there.

Finally, feel free to ask specific questions here on Stackoverflow and don't forget to use Google.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing things up for me :)

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I started with [Beginning iPhone Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430216263) by Jeff LaMarche. I liked the pace of the book and there were great relevant notes throughout the text as you went through sample projects.

After I felt a bit more comfortable with the language/platform, I dove into the [three20 project](https://github.com/facebook/three20). There's something super satisfying about being able to load up complex UI components, which three20 let's you do fairly easily. Plus, I found it a great way to find patterns on writing Objective-C.

Finally, I'd subscribe to a few Objective-C/iPhone blogs. Here are some that I read:

- Able Pear: http://blog.ablepear.com/
- Cocoanetics: http://www.cocoanetics.com/blog/
- iPhone Programming Tutorial: http://icodeblog.com/
- iDev Recipes: http://idevrecipes.com/ (really great idea)
- Marco: http://www.marco.org/
- Ole Begemann: http://oleb.net/
- Ray Wenderlich: http://www.raywenderlich.com/
- Jeff LaMarche: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/

Wish you the best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C is the place to start.  I would suggest Programming in Objective-C by Kochan and then move to iPhone Programming The Big Nerd Ranch Guide by Conway and Hillegass.  As mentioned by others, I wouldn't start with C...  Go Objective-C then a focus on iOS.